# ¿Cómo hacer negaciones de patrones completos con RegEx?

Tags: regex, seo, google-search-console

En Google Search Console ahora se permite filtrar las consultas por RegEx. Para ello, me sería muy util filtrar para evitar que intercepte el nombre de marca y sus variantes, es decir, negar completamente la cadena que contiene la marca.

Para ello pruebo con `[^marca]` pero no me funciona.

He probado también con `[^(marca)]` porque tiene que ser esa cadena concreta, pero tampoco me funciona.

También probé con `.*[^(marca)].*`

Comment: `[^marca]` coincide con **1 solo caracter**, cualquier caracter excepto `m`, `a`, `r` o `c`

Answer (score 0):

Para casi cualquier otra herramienta o lenguaje de programación, la respuesta es: *negar el resultado obtenido de la función/método*.

Para herramientas que no te ofrecen esa posibilidad, se usa un *negative lookahead*.
La expresión `(?!regex)` coincide cuando ***no está seguido por*** "regex".
Además, no consume caracteres (que en tu caso no es relevante).

En definitiva:

```
^(?!.*marca)
```

- En castellano: que el inicio del texto no esté seguido por cualquier cantidad de caracteres y luego `marca`.
- Prestale atención a cómo está anclado al inicio del texto. El `^` no tiene nada que ver con la negación, coincide con el inicio del texto. ¿Por qué se usa? Porque de lo contrario, podría coincidir con una posición intermedia del texto que no está seguida por `marca`, incluso cuando esa palabra está al inicio del texto.